# How to Parse a webpage

Tags: html, perl

I am attempting to extract the following from the EnviroCanada weather page.

I am trying to get for each hour as per the following.

Time | Thigh | Tlow | Humidity

7:00   |  23   |     22.9    |   30

Extracted HTML Page:

```
<tr>
         <td headers="header1" class="text-center vertical-center"> 7:00 </td>
        <td headers="header2" class="media vertical-center"><span class="pull-left"><img class="media-object" height="35" width="35" src="/weathericons/small/02.png" /></span><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
            <br />
            <br />
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <p>Partly Cloudy</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td headers="header3m" class=" metricData text-center vertical-center">23
                                            �(22.9)
                                        </td>
        <td headers="header3i" class=" imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">73
                                            �(73.2)
                                        </td>
        <td headers="header4m" class="metricData text-center vertical-center">
          <abbr title="West-Northwest">WNW</abbr> 8</td>
        <td headers="header4i" class="imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">
          <abbr title="West-Northwest">WNW</abbr> 5</td>
        <td headers="header6" class="metricData text-center vertical-center">30</td>
        <td headers="header6" class="imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">87</td>
        <td headers="header7" class="text-center vertical-center">83</td>
        <td headers="header8" class="metricData text-center vertical-center">20</td>
        <td headers="header8" class="imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">68</td>
        <td headers="header9m" class="metricData text-center vertical-center">100.7</td>
        <td headers="header9i" class="imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">29.7</td>
        <td headers="header10" class="metricData text-center vertical-center">24</td>
        <td headers="header10" class="imperialData hidden text-center vertical-center">15</td>
      </tr>
```

Code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TokeParser;


 my $url = "http://weather.gc.ca/past_conditions/index_e.html?station=yyz";
 my $page = get($url) ||
die "Could not load URL\n";


 my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$page) ||
die "Parse error\n";

 $parser->get_tag("td") foreach ();
 $parser->get_tag("");
 my $time = $parser->get_text();

  ??
 my $thigh = $parser->get_text();


 ???
 my $tlow = $parser->get_text();

 ???
 my $humid = $parser->get_text();
```

I'm Completely lost here

Comment: [HTML::TableExtract is very useful](https://www.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html).

Comment: I like Mojo::DOM for getting things out of HTML-pages, very nice to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you fetch the page with `LWP::Simple`, you can pick a specific tool depending on what needs to be done with it, instead of using a general parser.

In this case you have a table on your hands and I'd recommend [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm). With it you can cleanly retrieve table elements in a number of ways and then process them.  It can work with multiple tables, make use of headers, set up parsing preferences, and more. Normally you don't have to even look at the actual HTML. The module is a subclass of `HTML::Parser`. In my experience it's been a very good tool.

---

Here is some basic code, for this particular page and task.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $url = "http://weather.gc.ca/past_conditions/index_e.html?station=yyz";
my $page = get($url) or die "Can't load $url: $!";

my $headers = [ 'Time', 'Temperature', 'Humidex' ];

my $tec = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);
$tec->parse($page);

my $fmt = "%6s | %6s | %6s | %8s\n";    
printf($fmt, 'Time', 'T-high', 'T-low', 'Humidex');    

my ($time, $temp_hi, $temp_low, $hum);

foreach my $rrow ($tec->rows) {
    # Skip rows without expected data. Clean up leading/trailing spaces.
    next if $rrow->[0] !~ /^\s*\d?\d:\d\d/;
    my @row = map { s|^\s*||; s|\s*$||; $_ } @$rrow;
    # Process as needed
    ($time, $hum) = @row[0,2];
    ($temp_hi, $temp_low) = $row[1] =~ /(\d+) .* \( (\d+\.\d+) \)/xs;
    printf($fmt, $time, $temp_hi, $temp_low, $hum);
}
```

The first few rows of output

```
  Time | T-high |  T-low |  Humidex
 16:00 |     29 |   29.2 |       37
 15:00 |     27 |   27.2 |       37
 14:00 |     26 |   25.6 |       33
...
```

Comments.

The `headers` attribute for `new` makes it extract columns only under those headings. The loop variable is a *reference*, to an array with row elements. The elements are raw text in cells.

The first line skips rows that don't have the expected format – a possible digit `\d?` followed by another digit, then `:` then two digits. This is for time, `3:00` or `03:00`.

The arrayref `$rrow` is extracted into an array `@row` for clarity.
The sought elements in particular columns, `@row[0,2]` are used as they come. The one in `$row[1]` is parsed by a regex, which captures a number `(\d+)` and then two numbers separated by a `.`, with possible intervening text (`.*`). These captures are returned by regex, and assigned to the other two variables.

See the module's documentation and, if needed, tutorials on references [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and on regular expressions [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Another useful page is the  Data Structures Cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). For other introductions see [Tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html). They typically have links to more specific docs.

Comment: The question is how do i extract for 3:00, 5:00 etc and place in appropriate column? They all fall under the same headers tags.

Comment: I tried HTML::TableExtract (simple test) and it did not like 'my foreach': use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::Table;
my $doc = 'http://weather.gc.ca/past_conditions/index_e.html?station=yyz';
my $headers =  [ 'Time', 'Temperature' ];
 
my $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);
my $table_output = Text::Table->new(@$headers);
 $table_extract->parse_file($doc);
my ($table) = $table_extract->tables;
 
foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
    clean_up_spaces($row); # not shown for brevity
    $table_output->load($row);
}
 
print $table_output;

Comment: @BrianB  I've posted some basic but working code.  Will clean it up when I get time (even though it looks like you don't need that!).  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help

Comment: Sorry for this delayed response - I have a problem with the results it extacts up to 10:00 and skips 9:00 - 1:00 and I can't figure out why

Comment: The  issue is the it only extract times with 2 digits ie HH:MM not H:MM Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @BrianB  That turned out a long comment -- what I meant to say is: it's fixed.  In the line `next if ...` I changed `/\d\d:\d\d/` to `/\d?\d:\d\d/`. So, added one character, the `?`.  It means that the pattern before it is optional, there may be one or zero of it.  Please let me know if adding some explanation(s) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi zdim - thanks I will run it tomorrow - but I more than confident that your fix will work

Comment: I just ran it now - IT WORKS THANKS

Comment: @BrianB  Good, thanks for responding -- yes, this had to fix ... this.  It's tricky to come up with a general rule for any and all HTML format glitches.  Just let me know if something else comes up.

Comment: Hi Zdim can you provide some direction how how to do a horizontal column scrape? http://www.accuweather.com/en/ca/thunder-bay/p7b/hourly-weather-forecast/49563  I was trying to get TIME,TEMP,REAL,HUMIDITY

Comment: @BrianB  See the line `foreach my $row ...`. The `$row` is an _arrayref_, so `@$row` is the array.  You can look at the first element, `$row->[0]` and when it contains `'Temp'` you get the rest of the array for Temp. If it has `'Real'` then the remaining elements are values for that. Etc.  You do this by, say, `$row->[0] =~ /^\s*Temp/` (find `Temp` at start of the line except for possible spaces). If that's what you mean ...?  You also need to first _see_ the table, there could be empty cells etc (print out all rows and look at it).  The Humidity' seems to involve another table.

Comment: @BrianB  If arrayrefs are giving you trouble, extract it to an array and work with that -- `my @arr = @$refarr`.  Let me know if the previous comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response _zdim,  I just walked back in - I will go through this in the morning  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @BrianB Welcome -- let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi zdim  thanks for your help.  I am going to do some reading as I need to fully understand this utility better.  Thanks

Comment: @BrianB OK. Let me know if things pop up, and another question is always possible.  The basic thing you get from the module is that it parses the table (gets all the details out), and returns the rows in arrayrefs. That's the `forearh my $rowref (...)`. So you can then go through them and parse specifics in each row with a regex. That's `@row = @$rowref` and process `@row`.  (The `$row` and `@row` are completely different in Perl.  My naming of `$row` may have been confusing -- `$rrow` or `$rowref` are clearer.) And then the tool offers a few others goodies.

Comment: First of I appreciate your help here. This is obviously more advance than I had expected when I decided to tackle it. Thanks for the tutorial links I was off trying to get some background but your links look to be better than what I was coming across.  You made reference to 'other question'. Are you referring to that follow-up question within this stream or a separate question all together?  BTW I dont mean to waist your time with this, so again I appreciate your help.  Brian

Comment: @BrianB You are welcome.  Thanks for concern about my time! It's OK, if I didn't have time I'd let you know :)  I realized that it's probably things like references (and regex) that's in the way.  They are everywhere, if you use Perl in any way it's better to just go over it. Basics aren't  hard -- a reference is a pointer to some data structure (if C is OK).  Basic regex is simple-minded, then it gets hairy.  The "other question" I meant is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261542/parsing-webpage-how-to-extract-times-with-single-hour-digits).  I dropped a message there.