# Extracting information from HTML file using perl script

Tags: html, perl

This is my code to extract certain data under the header `Item Drop%`. I want to extract the `90.5%` under that header. But i can only extract the whole column not just that value. any idea ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TableExtract;
use LWP::Simple;

my $file = 'data.html';
unless ( -e $file ) {
    my $rc = getstore(
        'proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html',
        $file);
    die "Failed to download document\n" unless $rc == 200;
}



my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => qw(Item Drop%)]);

$te->parse_file($file);

my ($table) = $te->tables;

foreach my $ts (ts->tables) {
    print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), ");\n";
    foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
        print join(',', @$row), "\n";
    }
}
```

My `data.html` is:

```html
 ..
 ..
 ..
<table align = "center" class="" style= .......>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">EM</th>
<th colspan="2"><a href= "proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html" class = ..../th>
<td> 90.5%</td>
</tr>
..
..
..
..
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">EM</th>
<th colspan="2"><a href= "proj/Desktop/folder1/data.html" class = ..../th>
<td> 40%</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: The data snippet you provided contains no `table` tag and thus contains no tables. Please make a __minimal__ but __reproducible__ example, i.e. skip everything not actually needed  to show your problem (like use of LWP) and provide a complete data file which should work in your opinion but does not with your code.

Comment: Presumably there is a table there but you've only shown a fragment which isn't nearly enough for us to help you out.  Next, if `$te` is an "_undefined value_" as that error indicates then things are really not right since the good module you use couldn't even parse a table.  Then, the method `rows` goes on tables, so `$table->rows`.  See documentation; also, there are posts here with complete examples for processing tables (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871646/4653379), with links in it for two more complete examples)

Comment: Thanks for the comments , i think i solved it somehow. will update again soon !

Comment: @Vyshunavi OK, good :)  I just updated my comment with a link to a complete example, have a look

Comment: @zdim will do thanks ! i've updated my question. please take a look ~~

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still can't make sense of the HTML you show but it appears that the wanted data isn't under `EM` header, but rather in third column, so `$row->[2]`.  You should see that once your code is correct (it isn't at all as shown now) as it will plainly print it.  See linked examples (and docs)

Comment: Why aren't you using regular expressions? /ducks

Comment: @Holli  **_Do not use regular expressions for HTML. Use a suitable parser_**  That's been pounded on for years.  And, btw, `HTML::TableExtract` is an excellent tool for processing HTML tables.

Comment: @zdim i realise my html code is like a table within a table, its not just some basic table. can my codes instead look for keyword and extract the whole row of data from that particular keyword?

Comment: @Vyshunavi In short, yes, that's what one does in a way -- scan the parsed table for patterns and rules what allows us to extract precisely what we need.  I posted an example, please let me know how it goes with it.  Completing that table in the question (to an example of a reasonable size) would help.

Answer (score 3):

Here are basics, with the given table fragment completed to a meaningful table.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use HTML::TableExtract;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $filename = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new;
$te->parse_file($filename);    

my ($tbl) = $te->tables;  # one table in the sample file

my (@values1, @values2);  # for 90.5% and such, processing options

foreach my $row ($tbl->rows) { 
    # Tables often come with empty fields; keep them, for counting and such
    my @fields = map { defined($_) ? $_ : '--' } @$row;
    printf "%8s ", $_  for @fields;
    say ''; 

    # Criteria for how to identify the number aren't explained,
    # but may it be the fourth column in a row starting with 'EM'?
    if ($fields[0] =~ /^\s*EM\s*$/) {
        push @values1, $fields[3] =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//gr;  # see note in text
    }

    # Or is it simply the number ending with % sign?
    foreach my $fld (@fields) { 
        if ($fld =~ /\s*(.+)\s*%/ and looks_like_number($1)) { 
            push @values2, $1;
        }
    }
}
say "@values1";
say "@values2";
```

NOTE: The `/r` modifier in the regex was [added in v5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Non-destructive-substitution). If your Perl is older see footnote<sup>†</sup>

Much of processing is shown for a demo. One needn't print those values (once you figure out where the items of interest are), and I wouldn't replace `undef` fields with `--`, done for clearer printout, but rather with `''` (empty string). Also, we would need one criterion, not two.

Note that in the first case we keep the `%` sign, and use regex to clean up the spaces; in the second case the percentile sign is left out (and spaces end up cleaned out by regex naturally, in matching). These can both be adjusted to what you actually need of course.

Since neither the actual table nor data in it, nor the exact criteria,  are given I can only offer hints and examples of code. With more detail this can be made more specific.

Note, when it comes to nailing down the last details, often by regex, things tend to become picky and sensitive to details; so careful.

---

The html file, completed off of the fragment in the question, used above:

```
<html>    
<style> th, td { padding: 10px } </style>  <!-- to better see it -->

<table align="center" rules="all">    
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">EM</th>
    <th colspan="2"><a href="http://www.google.com">ggl</a></th>
    <td> 90.5%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>data</td> <td>more</td> <td>etc</td>
</tr>    

<tr>
<th rowspan="2">EM</th>
<th colspan="2"><a href="http://www.google.com">ggl</a></th>
<td> 0.0%</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>data</td> <td>more</td> <td>etc</td> </tr>    
</table>    

</html>
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  The `/r` modifier on the substitution regex makes it return the changed string (and it leaves the original as it is).  This is precisely what one wants in many situations, the one in the code here being a good example (we merely want to add the changed string to an array).

However, in Perls older than version 5.14, when this feature was introduced, one has to do otherwise: either create a new variable that has the change, if you need to keep the original unchanged, or change that original and then use it.

Since we are pruning extra spaces here it may well be best to simply change `$fields[3]` and then add it to the array.  So instead of

```
if ($fields[0] =~ /^\s*EM\s*$/) {
    push @values1, $fields[3] =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//gr;
}
```

do

```
if ($fields[0] =~ /^\s*EM\s*$/) {
    $fields[3] =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g;   # strip leading/trailing spaces
    push @values1, $fields[3];
}
```

Comment: ok let me try ur code and get back to u soon !

Comment: hi, it says that **bareword found where the operation expected** at  `if ($fields[0] =~ /^\s*EM\s*$/) {
        push @values1, $fields[3] =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//r;`

Comment: @Vyshunavi Not for me, it doesn't; I tested this (just did it again) and it works as expected. Are you using your real tables with this code?  I don't know your real data so this is written to process a file I made up from what you gave in the question (shown at the end).  If your actual HTML has a  different structure then you'd need to adjust the code accordingly.  I can't do that since I don't know your table.

Comment: @Vyshunavi On the other hand ... what version of Perl do you have?   That `/r` modifier in the regex was added in version 5.14.  If yours is earlier it won't work so let me know to add a different way in that case.

Comment: mine is v5.8.9, does that mean i cant use it? is there anyway i can sent u my html file ~

Comment: (ouch :) but that's like 20 years old :)  Can you update?  Anyway, I added a note on what code to use for Perl that old (since that `/r` feature in regex didn't exists at that time).  As for HTML, can you reduce it to  a short example that shows enough and add it to the question?  Another way is to upload to one of the many services out there which allow one to share files, like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Vyshunavi  (1) I put the workaround for older Perls into a footnote (2) As for `pastebin` (linked in comment above) --  go there and paste what you need in the box, then click "Create New Paste" button down the page. It saves that and makes a new webpage with it; copy the URL of that new page and post it here in a comment.  I just created an example and got [this URL](https://pastebin.com/gCQbqXUH).  (3) I looked up your Perl version on [Perl version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history), v5.8.9 is way more than 15 years old. Update please, if you can :).

Comment: its a company perl. so i cant update it sadly

Comment: @Vyshunavi Ah well :(  Tell'em that they are sporting shamefullly old equipment :(  Anyway -- does it work for you when you do a workaround (replace code) as explained in the footnote I added?   (And where's my link to a pastebin page with your HTML? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234956/discussion-between-vyshunavi-and-zdim).